# Using Open Google Earth cache file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, google-earth, image

I have a Google Earth cache file.

Is there any way to open the Google image from a cache file in QGIS 3?

I had done it in standalone PC successfully. Does it works also in Mapped Network Drive also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe **qgis** is able to process **Google Earth cache file**.
I advise you not to wast your time. Instead use **SAS Planet** alternative. It stores **tiles** locally as 
`file:///D:/Software/SAS.Planet/cache_gmt/z{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg`

Then you may use **TileLayer** or **MBTiles** plugin For version **under than 3.0**.

**qgis version 3.0 and above :**

Please use **XYZ Tiles** configured as follow :

[image: XYZ Tiles > New Connection]

Then add your Tiles Folder Path :
`file:///D://Software//SAS.Planet//cache_gmt//sat//z{z}//{y}//{x}.jpg`  **<--**

[image: Add XYZ Tiles specs here]

---

***Update:***
**SAS.PLANET Configuration :**

Click on **Settings>Options>**

**Default cache type :** *GlobalMapper Tiles*

**GlobalMapper Tiles (GMT) cache folder:** *cache_gmt*

**Reload** some cache again (by playing around the displayed map)

[image: SAS.PLANET GlobalMapper]

Comment: Yeah, Thank sir, Its working now.

Comment: Wow awsome, so happy you did it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for who are working on **leaflet** and need **SAS planet** data integration, you need only to add this line into your code to call the tiles:

```
var SAS = '/cache_gmt1/sat/z{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg',
```

[image: Leaflet SAS Planet Integration]

Comment: As I am new to it. How to setup my Apache server to use it for leaflet and do it SAS integration. I want to do it for LAN network. I want to open SAS tiles in LAN network in QGIS. Any help?

Comment: @Sachin you need to load all your maps all zoom levels online using SAS of course then copy the data folder (containing map tiles) to your htdocs or www or whatever.