# QGIS 3.14 + vector basemap : what syntax for a local style file URL?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have made small changes to a JSON style file which is used to get all layers informations (scale, style, legend...) from an ArcGIS Vector Tile Connection. I want to load it from local source, or a specific disk location but I can't find the right syntax on Windows.

I'm following the tutorial from Morgan Hite and it seems to work on Ubuntu:
https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/qgis-3-and-vector-map-tiles/

I tried the following syntax without success for now :

```
file:///P:/Random/QGIS/Styles/OSM_basemap
file:///P://Random//QGIS//Styles//OSM_basemap (idea come from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326125/using-open-google-earth-cache-file-in-qgis/326132#326132)
```

[image: connection]

Answer (score 2):

As simple as it was, I just forgot to mention the style file... and it's all you need

```
file:///P:/Random/QGIS/Styles/OSM_basemap/OSM_basemap_style.json
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it shows like this... What could be the reason for this? can you provide your style file?

[image]

Comment: I just needed to add "file://" + Path